# Fast R-Cnn and problems with spatialScale in BrainScript

Tags: cntk

I have the following code:

```
    model (features, rois) = {

        convOut  = convLayers (features)
        roiOut   = ROIPooling (convOut, rois, (9:9),spatialScale=64.0/196.0)
        z    = fcLayers (roiOut)


    }.z
```

Original taken from: cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN\BrainScript

What is spatialScale in ROIPooling and how do I calculate it?

If have found this in the output from the cntk.exe.

Validating --> z.convOut.z.rn3.r.r = RectifiedLinear (z.convOut.z.rn3.r.r._) : [49 x 49 x 64 x *] -> [49 x 49 x 64 x *]

Validating --> rois = InputValue() :  -> [4 x 1000 x *]

Validating --> z.roiOut = ROIPooling (z.convOut.z.rn3.r.r, rois) : [49 x 49 x 64 x *], [4 x 1000 x *] -> [9 x 9 x 64 x 1000 x *]

Answer (score 1):

spatial scale is the ratio of the spatial resolution of the input to the ROI and the spatial resolution of the input image to the network. 1/16.0 is the value used in the original Fast and Faster R-CNN implementation, this value depend on the network.

Pretty much, spatial scale is the scale of the input to ROI relative to the original image.

Thanks,
Emad

Comment: So my example i have have en ROI of 64x64 and a input image of 196x196. This will give an spatialScale = 64/196 = 0,32

Comment: What the input resolution to your ROI node, not the ROI size.

Comment: Ok, If I understand you correctly you are asking for the input resolution to the roiOut. I have added what I think is the resolution to the question.

Comment: To the roi input not output, for example let say your network is y = G(x). and your roi layer is as follow: k = roi(l) somewhere inside G(), then your spatial should be: l.height / x.height, the aspect ratio of `x` and `l` need to be the same.